# sed to match multiline range and replace

Tags: regex, sed

I have the file below

```
next: 
    {
     host = "http://nxt-newepisode.xcfm.crata.dive.com/err1.2.2/table/kenny.xml.gz"
    };

second:
   {
     host = "http://nxt-secondepisode.xcfm.crata.dive.com/err1.2.2/table/kenny.xml.gz"
    };
```

I want to replace the url based on `nxt:{ host = ""` and `second: { host = ""`. How can I filter this using sed with a multiline match, as these are on multiple lines?

I tried:

```
sed -i '/second : {\rhost/s#"http://.*"#"next.com"#' file.txt
```

It doesn't work. I am using `\r` for new line but I also tried `\n`.

Comment: Try `sed -i '/second:/{N;N;s#"http://.*"#"next.com"#}' file`. This assumes you have the URL on the second line below `second:`

Comment: thank you . will try . what does N and N mean

Comment: The sed command `N` appends the next line of input to the current line being matched. `N;N` does it twice. The `;` is put between two commands.

Comment: `N` appends the newline and then subsequent line to the pattern space. So, the `s`ubstitute command is run on `second:
   {
     host = "http://nxt-secondepisode.xcfm.crata.dive.com/err1.2.2/table/kenny.xml.gz"` text. Just let know if this structure is fixed and we may leverage this.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer it worked . You can put it as an answer with explanation.can we filter it based on host key word as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we can assume you have the URL on the second line below `second:` you may use

```
sed -i '/second:/{N;N;s#"http://.*"#"next.com"#}' file
```

See this [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/S0nB7C).

`N` appends the newline and then subsequent line to the pattern space. So, the `s`ubstitute command is run on the following text:

```
second:
   {
     host = "http://nxt-secondepisode.xcfm.crata.dive.com/err1.2.2/table/kenny.xml.gz"
```

If it is not known which line it is exactly, you may loop before you find the lione that starts with 0+ spaces, then `host =`, and only then run substitution:

```
sed -i '/second:/{:a;n;/^ *host *=/!ba;s#"http://.*"#"next.com"#}' file
```

See this [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/Y8u5VE).

Here,

- `/second:/` - once a line contains `second:`
- `:a` - set a label named `a`
- `n` - discard the current pattern space and read the next line into it
- `/^ *host *=/!ba` - if the line does not (`!`) start with 0+ spaces, `host`, 0+ spaces, `=`, then go back (`b`) to label `a` position
- `s#"http://.*"#"next.com"#` - run the substitution.

Literal spaces can be replaced with `[[:space:]]*`, `[[:blank:]]*` or `\s*` to match any whitespace depending on what works in your `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;/^second:/{:b;n;/^\S+:/ba;/(^\s*host = ")[^"]*/s##\1newUrl#;Tb}' file
```

The replacement of a new url is confined to the `second:` section.

On encountering another section the processing is repeated.

Within a `second:` section the line begining `host = "` is sought and the value within double quotes replaced.

Otherwise the process is repeated until either condition above is met or the end of file.